# Importing map found on the Internet to QGIS

Tags: qgis-processing, geoprocessing, field-mapping, thematic-map, raster-functions

I am new to QGIS and I have learned some of the basics.

Now, I have found a Soil Map of Germany I want to work with on the internet.

My tasks now are as follows.

1. To reduce the size of the map with its properties to just the map of my city.

Any suggestions on how to go about this tasks?

This is the link to the map

https://www.bgr.bund.de/EN/Themen/Boden/Projekte/Informationsgrundlagen_abgeschlossen/BUEK1000/BUEK1000_en.html

At the end of the link, it says there is a metadata, GIS data and web services (WMS) of the map. Confused as to which to file/format is appropriate.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We're not really a tutorial site; instead, we help when you find a tutorial and have difficulty with it.

Comment: In what format is this "Soil Map of Germany"?

Comment: Is this map an image? A PDF? A shapefile? Can you show us it or give us the link? Please edit your question and supply some more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the map in QGIS using Web Map Service (WMS). In the browser-panel, right-click WMS, add a name and the following URL: https://services.bgr.de/wms/boden/buek200/?
Than close by clicking OK. Now you have a new WMS-connection that you can expand. Select an item and drag and drop it to your layers-panel and the map will load: see screenshot:

[image]

Select 3857 as project  EPSG (bottom right in your QGIS-window, see following screenshot). Select different layers for the different regions that are available. If you have a basemap like OpenStreetMap in the background, you can also apply layer blending modes to see both maps combined - I used multiply as layer blending mode, see screenshot here.

[image]

In the product center you can also load the product info-sheet as pdf with detailed information and meta-data as well as contact-information. As far as I can see, there is only access as WMS available, that means you can load the image via this web-service in your QGIS window, but there is no way to safe the data locally on your computer. Distribution as image-file (png, jpeg, gif) mentions n/a (not available). So if you need the data for more than just viewing and inspecting in QGIS, I guess best is to get in contact with the data-owner with the contact information provided in the pdf mentioned above:
[geodatenmanagement@bgr.de](http://mailto:geodatenmanagement@bgr.de)
https://produktcenter.bgr.de

However, you have the data available also as ESRI ShapeFile, thus not as image, but as vector data - this is what you can use to work locally. Download form here: https://download.bgr.de/bgr/boden/BUEK250/shp/buek250_mg_utm_v55.zip
Just unzip the downloaded folder and add (e.g. by drag and drop) the shp-File (buek250_mg_utm_v55.shp - the largest file) to qgis.